# Tuning Tensorflow Estimators based on batch size, hash bucket size, memory etc on CPU?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard, tensorflow-estimator

We're testing out various estimators such as LinearEstimator, DNNClassifier etc. Right now we are restricted to use only CPU for training, and we're testing out parameters and levers such as

- CPU: 8~32 cpu's
- Memory: 16~48 GB
- Batch/Buffer size(dataset.batch(n)) : n=128~512
- Hash bucket_size: 10,000 ~ 500,000
- Number of threads: Tensorflow default, which should be number of logical cores
- Optimizer: GradientDescent, FtrlOptimizer

Result: global steps per second * batch_size of around 20~50

So we're getting via Tensorboard global steps per second * bucket_size of around 20~50, and increasing CPU and memory has its limits.

We see similar results regardkess of Optimizer and its configurations.

Are we doing something wrong, and are there other levers we can use? Is there a limit as to how much you can optimize your model training methods, and should we move on to GPU's and take advantage of its matrix multiplication efficiencies?

Answer (score 0):

You can try optimizing your input pipeline with Dataset API. Consider converting your data to tfrecords, it can give substantial improvements. If you have multiple CPUs you can setup a cluster. But it all depends heavily on what data you have. And take a look

https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/performance/datasets

https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/performance/overview